Matrix of an Inner Product and Spectral Theorem
My linear algebra has become very rusty and now I've confused myself entirely.
Let $V$ be an inner product space over an $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$. Moreover, let the set of vectors $$\mathcal{E} = \{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$$ form a basis for $V$. Denoting the inner product by $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ we may identify it with the matrix $A$, whose entries satisfy $$a_{ij} = \langle e_i , e_j \rangle.$$
Any vector $v \in V$ can be uniquely identified with a vector $[x]_{\mathcal{E}} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, determined by the representation of $v$ in the basis $\mathcal{E}$. For $u,v \in V$, we then have $$\langle u,v \rangle = [u]_{\mathcal{E}}^TA[v]_{\mathcal{E}}.$$
$A$ is a symmetric real matrix. By the Spectral Theorem, there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ whose $j$-th column is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_j$, for $j = 1,\dots,n$. Hence, $$U^{\top}AU = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n).$$
Since $U$ is invertible, identifying its $j$-th column with $[f_j]_{\mathcal{E}}$ for all $j = 1, \dots, n$ we obtain a new basis of $V$, $$\mathcal{F} = \{f_1, \dots f_n\},$$ composed of eigenvectors of $A$.
We can run the same logic and define the inner product in terms of the matrix $B$ with entries $$b_{ij} = \langle f_i,f_j \rangle.$$ It is easy to verify by components that $$ B = U^{\top}AU = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n).$$
This is where I have confused myself. The Spectral Theorem is sometimes stated as: If A is a symmetric real matrix, V has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of A. Does orthonormality not exactly imply that $B = I$, or equivalently all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to $1$? I would be grateful if someone could clear this up for me!

Perhaps things will be clearest when $n = 1$. Let $(V, \langle -, - \rangle))$ be a one-dimensional real inner product space, with basis $(e)$. Suppose that we measure
$$ \langle e, e \rangle = 2,$$
so the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}2\end{pmatrix}.$ This is diagonalised by the orthogonal matrix $U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and if we identify its columns in terms of the basis $(e)$ and pull back we get $f = e$. So we have really done nothing to our original basis.

Suppose you really do want to produce an orthonormal basis doing something like this, starting from the inner product space $V$ and a basis $\mathcal{E}$. Define the matrix $A$ as you did:
$$ A \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R}), \quad A_{ij} := \langle e_i, e_j \rangle.$$
The matrix $A$ is symmetric with positive eigenvalues, so by the spectral theorem it diagonalises $A = U D U^T$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries. Define $A^{1/2} = U D^{1/2} U^{-1}$, a particular square root of $A$, which is also symmetric with positive eigenvalues. Then define the basis $\mathcal{F}$ to be
$$ [f_i]_\mathcal{E} = A^{-1/2} [e_i]_\mathcal{E}.$$
Now you have
$$ \langle f_i, f_j \rangle = [f_i]_\mathcal{E}^T A [f_j]_\mathcal{E} = [e_i]_\mathcal{E} A^{-1/2} A A^{-1/2} [e_j]_\mathcal{E} = \delta_{ij}.$$

Thanks for clarifying this. So in the statement "$V$ has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$", orthonormal solely refers to the fact that there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ whose columns are eigenvectors of $A$, rather than implying the existence of such a matrix $U$ with $U^TAU = I$.

@Algebro1000 Yes - the matrix $A$ is not a linear operator on $V$, it is just recording the pairings of a bilinear map. So the statement that there is an orthogonal $U$ such that $U^T A U$ is diagonal with real eigenvalues is really a statement about symmetric real matrices, not your original space. It's a subtle point.
